# File::extension() doesn't work with if in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, file-extension

I have run into a weird problem. I am using `File::extension($file)` and actually getting the answer as 'pdf'. I `var_dump()` the `File::extension($file)` and it shows the value if string with 3 characters that is 'pdf' for sure.

Then I try to compare it in an if statement, but it goes into the if statement where it shouldn't. It's such a weird behaviour.

```
$fileType = File::extension($request->frequencyPlan->getClientOriginalName());

if ($fileType != 'pdf' || $fileType != 'doc') {
    return $this->showEstablishmentsEdit('fileTypeErrorForPDF');
};
```

Am I missing out something?

---

P.S: For those who are wondering, I couldn't use mimeType validator because I get another error

> 'Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)'

and I think the upper if statement should work anyway.

Comment: to give you a complete answer, **frequencyPlan** is the file input name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement has a logic error.

When `$fileType` is equal to `pdf`, your `if` condition will still evaluate to `true`. `$fileType != 'pdf'` will be `false`, but the second half, `$fileType != 'doc'` is `true`, and since you have "or"ed these conditions together, the result is `true`.

Let `$fileType = 'pdf'`.
Then `$fileType != 'pdf'` is `false`.
Then `$fileType != 'doc'` is `true`.

Therefore, `($fileType != 'pdf' || $fileType != 'doc') === (false || true) === (true)`, which enters the `if` branch.

I'm assuming you want to enter the `if` branch if the extension is not "pdf" **and** is not "doc".

Your code should be:

```
if ($fileType != 'pdf' && $fileType != 'doc') {
    return $this->showEstablishmentsEdit('fileTypeErrorForPDF');
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$fileType = $request->frequencyPlan->extension();

if ($fileType !== 'pdf' && $fileType !== 'doc') {
  return $this->showEstablishmentsEdit('fileTypeErrorForPDF');
};
```

and for your other issues:

> 'Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)'

**Hosting server:**

- contact the hosting provider and tell him to enable this extension **php_fileinfo**.

**Local hosting:**

- what's your operating system?